# Init requires that the types T<U> and X: T<U> be equivalent

Tags: swift, generics, type-erasure

I’ve been stuck on similar problems for a year.  I’m sorry I don’t know how to explain this issue without an example.

The issue centres around the fact that: `T<U>` and `X:T<U>` are not equivalent. I want to add stored properties to `X` so it's not enough to simply use `T<U>` and use an extension.

I’m doing this in the context of a type-erased delegate. If you have any suggestions for how to improve this post title, please let me know.
What can I do to resolve this issue?

Base Types:

```
protocol RouterDelegate: class {
    associatedtype RT: Routing
    associatedtype R: Router<RT>
    func routerDidSomething(_ router: R)
}

protocol Routing {}

class Router<RT: Routing> {
    var delegate: AnyRouterDelegate<Router<RT>, RT>?
}
```

Type-erased wrapper around delegate:

```
fileprivate class AnyRouterDelegateBase<R: Router<RT>, RT>: RouterDelegate {
    func routerDidSomething(_ router: R) { }
}

fileprivate final class AnyRouterDelegateBox<D: RouterDelegate>: AnyRouterDelegateBase<D.R, D.RT> {
    weak var delegate: D?
    
    init(_ delegate: D) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    override func routerDidSomething(_ router: R) {
        self.delegate?.routerDidSomething(router)
    }
}

final class AnyRouterDelegate<R: Router<RT>, RT>: RouterDelegate {
    
    private let base: AnyRouterDelegateBase<R, RT>
    
    init<D: RouterDelegate>(_ delegate: D) where D.R == R, D.RT == RT {
        self.base = AnyRouterDelegateBox(delegate)
    }
    
    func routerDidSomething(_ router: R) {
        self.base.routerDidSomething(router)
    }
    
}
```

Concrete implementations/Subclasses

```
struct PortRouting: Routing { }
final class PortRouter: Router<PortRouting> { }
protocol PortRouterDelegate: RouterDelegate where R == PortRouter, RT == PortRouting { }
```

Use

```
class Controller: PortRouterDelegate {
    
    let router = PortRouter()
    
    init() {
        self.router.delegate = AnyRouterDelegate(self)
        //*** ERROR: - Initializer 'init(_:)' requires the types 'Router<PortRouting>' and 'PortRouter' be equivalent
    }
    
    func routerDidSomething(_ router: PortRouter) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

removed redundant constraints:

```
protocol RouterDelegate: class {
    associatedtype RT: Routing
    typealias R = Router<RT>
    func routerDidSomething(_ router: R)
}

protocol Routing {}

class Router<RT: Routing> {
    var delegate: AnyRouterDelegate<RT>?
}

fileprivate class AnyRouterDelegateBase<RT: Routing>: RouterDelegate {
    func routerDidSomething(_ router: R) { }
}

fileprivate final class AnyRouterDelegateBox<D: RouterDelegate>: AnyRouterDelegateBase<D.RT> {
    weak var delegate: D?
    
    init(_ delegate: D) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    override func routerDidSomething(_ router: R) {
        self.delegate?.routerDidSomething(router)
    }
}

final class AnyRouterDelegate<RT: Routing>: RouterDelegate {
    private let base: AnyRouterDelegateBase<RT>
    
    init<D: RouterDelegate>(_ delegate: D) where D.RT == RT {
        self.base = AnyRouterDelegateBox(delegate)
    }
    
    func routerDidSomething(_ router: R) {
        self.base.routerDidSomething(router)
    }
    
}

struct PortRouting: Routing { }
final class PortRouter: Router<PortRouting> { }
protocol PortRouterDelegate: RouterDelegate where RT == PortRouting {
    
}

class Controller: PortRouterDelegate {
    
    let router: Router<PortRouting> = PortRouter()
    
    init() {
        self.router.delegate = AnyRouterDelegate(self)
        
    }
    
    func routerDidSomething(_ router: Router<PortRouting>) { }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that in `routerDidSomething(_:)` I need `PortRouter` instead of `Router<PortRouting>` because `PortRouter` has unique properties. I think I still need to define `R` as an associated type in terms of `Router<RT>`. But I can solve it by just adding `where RT == PortRouting, R == PortRouter`.